Tangent vector fields on the sphere
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{S}^2$ be an open set such that $\Omega \cap -\Omega =\emptyset$, where $-\Omega =\{-x\in \mathbb{S}^2: x\in \Omega\}$. Is it possible to have a continuous unit tangent vector field $V(x)$ on $\mathbb{S}^2 \backslash (\Omega \cup -\Omega)$  such that

$||V||=1$ on $\mathbb{S}^2 \backslash (\Omega \cup -\Omega)$, and $\mathbb{S}^2 \backslash (\Omega \cup -\Omega)$ has non-empty interior and $C^1$ boundary.
$V(x)\cdot n(x) =0$ for all $x\in \partial ( \Omega \cup -\Omega) $? ($n$ is the unit normal vector on the boundary of $\Omega$ and $-\Omega$).
$V(x)=V(-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{S}^2 \backslash (\Omega \cup -\Omega)$.

Note that $V$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb{S}^2$. Intuitively, this seems impossible, but I am uncertain how to prove it. I would appreciate any hints or references. It is possible that a generalized version of the Poincaré-Hopf theorem could be applicable in demonstrating this.

I’m lost. What is $\Omega_0$? $n$ is the unit tangent?

@TedShifrin Sorry, I just revised the question. I meant $-\Omega$ by $\Omega_0$.

@Tom Thank you. It now says $n$ is the unit normal vector on the boundary.

If $\Omega$ is a single point, then I don’t know what condition 2 means. Is $\Omega$ open?

I don't think that the question makes sense without specifying your assumptions about $\Omega$. In the current form, you could take $\Omega$ to be the open northern hemisphere, then $V$ has to be defined on the equator only and to be tangent to the equator there and satisfy $V(-x)=V(x)$, and of course, this is possible.

@AndreasCap Thank you. I assume that $\mathbb{S}^2 \backslash (\Omega \cup -\Omega)$ has non-empty interior. I added this assumption.

This is not enough either since it says nothing about the boundary, so the condition on the normal does not really make sense. You can for example take a snow-flake curve (which is nowhere differentiable) move it into the open northern hemisphere in such a way that the north pole lies in the interior and then define $\Omega$ to be this interior. Then the boundary of $\Omega\cup-\Omega$ consists of two copies of the snow-flake curve ...

@AndreasCap We may assume that the boundary is $C^1$. I revised the question.

Yes, such a field exists. In the hope a picture is worth a lot of words:

In more detail, it suffices to let $\Omega$ be a spherical cap, and to take the field to be rotationally-symmetric about the vertical axis, with its restriction to a longitude (blue) pointing northward, and its transverse component an odd function of latitude (so the field takes equal values in Cartesian space at antipodal points of the sphere).
The field shown is defined for latitude $v$ satisfying $|v| \leq v_{0} < \pi/2$. Define $k$ so that $kv_{0} = \pi/2$. Modulo scaling down for clarity, the field takes value $(\sin kv, \cos kv)$ at $(u, v)$, pushed forward to the sphere by geographic coordinates with longitude $u$ and latitude $v$.

What software was used to generate this figure? It looks very nice!

@whpowell96 Thanks! I use ePiX. (The link is a good overview for now, but I no longer have access to the page, so over time it will go out of date.)
